# django nested foreignkey set query

Tags: django

I wanted  to filter on the _set of an item, however in the problem below while i was doing this, it wasn't on the field i thought it was. I needed to use rating__rating to get the rating column of the  rating table in the post table.

in django, i have this:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField(max_length=345)
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story)
    ...

class Rating(models.Model)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

and then i can find all the ratings for a given post that are have a set value:

```
def getPostsForStory(id):
    return arrangeCountOfRatings(Post.objects.filter(story=id))

def arrangeCountOfRatings(postList):
    for post in postList:
        post.rateA = post.rating_set.filter(rating=rateA).count()
    return postList
```

but how do i do this from a given story? That is, say i wanted to apply the above process of getting the counts for each post, but given a Story object?

```
def getStoryItemsForUser(request):
    return arrangeCountOfItems(Story.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)

def arrangeCountOfItems(storyList):
    for story in storyList:
        story.rateA = story.post_set.filter(rating=rateA).count()
    return storyList
```

doesn't get me what i want (the counts are all wrong - either zero of, if there are posts with ratings, 1

EDIT:

ah. The problem is thus:

```
story.rateA = story.post_set.filter(rating=rateA).count()
```

does not search for  what i wanted - it is searching effectively on rating__id instead of rating__rating

so i just changed it to read rating__rating, simple.

Comment: Might want to look into moving some of those `for` loops into the QuerySet. Database hits slow things down. Check out [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

Comment: story.post_set.filter counts posts count, not ratings count. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
    story.rateA = Rating.objects.filter(rating=ratingA, post__story=story).count()
```

EDIT: The same is valid for post ratings(and equivalent to your code):

```
    post.rateA = Rating.objects.filter(rating=ratingA, post=post).count()
```

Counting ratings for the specified post/story.